# Predict.proba in Naive Bayes

Tags: probability, predict, naivebayes

I've question about how to convert the result of predict.proba in Naive Bayes into percent. I've already try some but failed. I wanna get the result become like 50%, 100%. This is the sample of my code

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
import itertools
plt.style.use('ggplot')

class bayesNaive:
    def __init__(self, dataTrainInput):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(dataTrainInput, delimiter=";", encoding="latin-1")
def encoderLabel(self):
    self.lb = LabelEncoder()
    df = pd.DataFrame(self.data,
                      columns=["laboratory_registration_id", "Albumin","Asam Urat", "Basofil", "Basofil Absolut","BE", "Berat Jenis", "Besi (Fe/iron)", "Eosinofil", "Eosinofil Absolut", "Eritrosit","Ferritin", "Free T4", "Glukosa Darah 2 jam PP", "Glukosa Darah Puasa","Glukosa Darah Sewaktu", "Hb-A1c", "Hematokrit", "Hemoglobin", "Kalium (K)","Klorida (Cl)", "Kolesterol HDL", "Kolesterol LDL", "Kolesterol Total", "Kreatinin","Leukosit", "Limfosit", "Limfosit Absolut", "MCH", "MCHC", "MCV", "Monosit","Monosit Absolut", "MPV", "Natrium (Na)", "Neutrofil Absolut", "Neutrofil Segmen","O2 Saturasi", "pCO2", "PDW", "pH", "pO2", "RDW-CV", "RDW-SD", "T CO2", "TIBC","T3 Total", "T4 Total", "Trigliserida", "Trombosit", "Troponin T", "TSH", "Ureum", "Age", "Gender", "Disease"])
    data1 = self.data["Bakteri"]
    data2 = self.data["Bilirubin"]
    data3 = self.data["Blood"]
    data5 = self.data["Epitel"]
    data6 = self.data["Eritrosit Urin"]
    data7 = self.data["Faktor Rheumatoid (RF)"]
    data8 = self.data["Glukosa"]
    data9 = self.data["HBsAg"]
    data10 = self.data["Kejernihan"]
    data11 = self.data["Keton"]
    data12 = self.data["Kristal"]
    data13 = self.data["Leukosit Urin"]
    data14 = self.data["Nitrit"]
    data15 = self.data["Protein"]
    data16 = self.data["Silinder"]
    data17 = self.data["Urobilinogen"]
    data18 = self.data["Warna"]

    x1 = self.lb.fit_transform(data1)
    x2 = self.lb.fit_transform(data2)
    x3 = self.lb.fit_transform(data3)
    x5 = self.lb.fit_transform(data5)
    x6 = self.lb.fit_transform(data6)
    x7 = self.lb.fit_transform(data7)
    x8 = self.lb.fit_transform(data8)
    x9 = self.lb.fit_transform(data9)
    x10 = self.lb.fit_transform(data10)
    x11 = self.lb.fit_transform(data11)
    x12 = self.lb.fit_transform(data12)
    x13 = self.lb.fit_transform(data13)
    x14 = self.lb.fit_transform(data14)
    x15 = self.lb.fit_transform(data15)
    x16 = self.lb.fit_transform(data16)
    x17 = self.lb.fit_transform(data17)
    x18 = self.lb.fit_transform(data18)

    df1 = pd.DataFrame(x1, columns=['Bakteri'])
    df2 = pd.DataFrame(x2, columns=['Bilirubin'])
    df3 = pd.DataFrame(x3, columns=['Blood'])
    df5 = pd.DataFrame(x5, columns=['Epitel'])
    df6 = pd.DataFrame(x6, columns=['Eritrosit Urin'])
    df7 = pd.DataFrame(x7, columns=['Faktor Rheumatoid (RF)'])
    df8 = pd.DataFrame(x8, columns=['Glukosa'])
    df9 = pd.DataFrame(x9, columns=['HBsAg'])
    df10 = pd.DataFrame(x10, columns=['Kejernihan'])
    df11 = pd.DataFrame(x11, columns=['Keton'])
    df12 = pd.DataFrame(x12, columns=['Kristal'])
    df13 = pd.DataFrame(x13, columns=['Leukosit Urin'])
    df14 = pd.DataFrame(x14, columns=['Nitrit'])
    df15 = pd.DataFrame(x15, columns=['Protein'])
    df16 = pd.DataFrame(x16, columns=['Silinder'])
    df17 = pd.DataFrame(x17, columns=['Urobilinogen'])
    df18 = pd.DataFrame(x18, columns=['Warna'])

    return pd.concat([df1, df2, df3, df5, df6, df7, df8, df9, df10, df11, df12, df13, df14, df15, df16, df17, df18, df], axis=1)

def split_label(self):
    res = self.encoderLabel()
    X = res.iloc[:, :-1].values
    Y = res['Disease'].values
    return X, Y

def test_split(self):
    X, Y = self.split_label()
    X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X,Y, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
    return X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test

def Classify_lab(self):
    try:
        X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = self.test_split()
        # print(X_test.shape)
        model = GaussianNB()
        model_train = model.fit(X_train, Y_train)

        model_score = model_train.score(X_test, Y_test)
        accuracy = round(model_score * 100, 2)
        predicted = model_train.predict(X_test)
        Y_prob = model_train.predict_proba(X_test)
        report=classification_report(Y_test, predicted)
        conf_m = confusion_matrix(Y_test, predicted)
        # "precision: tp/(tp+fp)"
        # "recall: tp/(tp+fn)"
        # "f1-score: (2xprecisionxrecall)/(precision+recall)"

        # print(test.shape)
        test.columns = ["Bakteri", "Bilirubin", "Blood", "Epitel","Eritrosit Urin","Faktor Rheumatoid (RF)", "Glukosa", "HBsAg", "Kejernihan", "Keton", "Kristal", "Leukosit Urin", "Nitrit", "Protein", "Silinder", "Urobilinogen", "Warna","laboratory_registration_id", "Albumin", "Asam Urat", "Basofil", "Basofil Absolut","BE", "Berat Jenis", "Besi (Fe/iron)", "Eosinofil", "Eosinofil Absolut", "Eritrosit","Ferritin", "Free T4", "Glukosa Darah 2 jam PP", "Glukosa Darah Puasa","Glukosa Darah Sewaktu", "Hb-A1c", "Hematokrit", "Hemoglobin", "Kalium (K)","Klorida (Cl)", "Kolesterol HDL", "Kolesterol LDL", "Kolesterol Total", "Kreatinin","Leukosit", "Limfosit", "Limfosit Absolut", "MCH", "MCHC", "MCV", "Monosit","Monosit Absolut", "MPV", "Natrium (Na)", "Neutrofil Absolut", "Neutrofil Segmen","O2 Saturasi", "pCO2", "PDW", "pH", "pO2", "RDW-CV", "RDW-SD", "T CO2", "TIBC","T3 Total", "T4 Total", "Trigliserida", "Trombosit", "Troponin T", "TSH", "Ureum","Age", "Gender"]

        labels = pd.DataFrame(predicted)
        # print(Y_prob)
        print("bulatan")
        # Y_prob[:, 1:3] = np.around(Y_prob[:,1:3],decimals=1)
        probability = pd.DataFrame(Y_prob)
        labels.columns = ["Disease"]
        probability.columns = ["Diabetes mellitus", "Ginjal","Jantung", "Thalassemia"]

        result = pd.concat([test, labels, probability], axis=1)
        # Z = self.decodeLabel(X_test)
        # print("Ini", Z)
        # exit()
        return [result, str(accuracy), report, conf_m]
    except ValueError as v:
        print(v)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print('File not found')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    dataTrainInput = "perc4.csv"
    obj = bayesNaive(dataTrainInput)
    print(obj.Classify_lab())
```

In Classify_lab(), I predict the probability of other targets

```
 Y_prob = model_train.predict_proba(X_test)
```

Then, I create dataframe

```
probability = pd.DataFrame(Y_prob)
```

When I run probability, I ll get this result

```
     Diabetes mellitus      ...          Thalassemia
0         1.000000e+00      ...         0.000000e+00
1         5.693959e-28      ...         0.000000e+00
2        1.610343e-182      ...         0.000000e+00
3         4.347851e-04      ...         9.949097e-01
4         2.611833e-24      ...         0.000000e+00
5         6.281686e-32      ...         1.000000e+00
6         1.000000e+00      ...         3.472943e-99
7        2.580374e-132      ...         0.000000e+00
8         1.457926e-26      ...         1.000000e+00
9         1.000000e+00      ...         0.000000e+00
10        4.993317e-33      ...         1.000000e+00
```

And if I run probability in HTML , I ll get this result

[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/988gi.png)

Thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

Total Probability of NB is 1. In your cases you can see whereever there is 1.0, for remaining columns the probability is either 0 or very close to 0. You can simply take maximum out of the array returned and multiply by 100.